# Mac OS X application that can list frame sizes, frame rates and codecs of videos in a directory

Tags: macos, video, codec, framerate

I have zillions of videos encoded in different frame sizes, frame rates, codecs, etc. I would like to be able to use some sort of application that can list all these characteristics of videos in a given directory.

Do you guys know something out there that can do the trick on Mac OS X Snow Leopard? (preferably open source).

Comment: Deleted comments as they added no value to the actual question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) is an open-source command line tool able to do what you request.

If you want to install it from source code, take a look at: [FFmpeg on Mac OS X How-To](http://stephenjungels.com/jungels.net/articles/ffmpeg-howto.html).

If you want a GUI interface, check out: [FFmpegX](http://www.ffmpegx.com/index.html).